# как сделать выборку данных из текстового файла

Tags: php, mysql

как сделать выборку данных из текстового файла и перенести эти данные в mysql? в текстовом файле данные даны в столбцах и каждый из этих столбцов надо занести в разные поля в БД

Comment: добавьте к вопросу малую часть файла что бы понять формат данных

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего речь идет о формате ".csv", если так то текстовый файл можно импортировать напрямую через gui интерфейс phpmyadmin в вкладке импорт файл.